# how to revise a const int value c++

Tags: c++, variables, constants

I have a "expected constant expression" error.
This is my error part:

```
 int row=counter/4;     
int goals[row][4];---> this part has error for "row" variable
```

how to define "row" variable like a constant value? or how to solve this problem?

Comment: And how have you defined counter ?

Comment: Please, post a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sorry but it doesnt matter, counter value is getting from a file; like that  'FILE *fffile;                                                    
 fffile= fopen("C:\\goals.txt","r" );
 int i=0;
 int j=0;
 int counter=0;
 int c=0;
 while(!feof(fffile)){ //dosyanın sonuna kadar gitme
  fscanf(fffile,"%d",&c);                         
  counter++;'

Comment: @ozz Of course it *does* matter. You cannot create a *compile-time* constant from a value obtained at *runtime.* You probably want `std::vector`.

Comment: @JérômeLeducq, `std::array` is not an option here, it will suffer from the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

C++ does not allow arrays of variable size. In your example, `row` is not a constant, and as such, can not be used to specify array size.

To workaround this, you might either switch to C (which does allow such arrays) or use C++ constructs - such as `std::vector`.

Syntaxically correct change would be to rephrase row as

```
const size_t row = counter / 4;
```

But than you'd need `counter` const, which you would not be able to do if you are getting it from the user input.

Answer (score 0):

you can use only compile time constants in array declaring.

constexpr could help you,

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

but not for all compilers, look for the answer here:

[constexpr function as array size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29674152/constexpr-function-as-array-size)